# Alternatives to some namespaces C# in Node.js

Tags: c#, node.js

I was wondering if there are alternatives for **System.Drawing** from C# to Node.js, I wanted to use as classes **Point, Rectangle**, **Bitmap**. I wan't to make this in **server-side**. Does Node.js support this or is there a library that has what is needed?

Comment: `System.Threading.Monitor` doesn't exists mostly because NodeJs is limited to single-thread, so it has no need for syncronization primitives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Javascript world, the favorite API for drawing is the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API). Most browsers implement at least a subset of it. And good things like charting code run on top of it.

In server-side (nodejs) code you'll need the [canvas npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) to use that API. It's a faithful implementation. You can draw stuff, then save it to image files or send it to browsers.

It's a big package with compiled code. So, make sure its not-quite-trivial `npm install` operation works correctly on your staging and production machines.

Answer (score 0):

No, This system.Drawing etc doesn't supported by node.js, if you want to draw things in node.js. Go for the **canvas**, it will be your solution.

For your information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API